# Solucionar problema ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE con PHPmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, smtp

Hola he realizado una aplicación de envío de e-mails para un cliente con la cual quiere enviar sus catálogos de productos a sus clientes. La tabla de la cual sacamos los e-mails contiene unos 5000 registros. La cuestión es que al hacer un envio con filtros a por ejemplo 10 emails, la aplicación funciona correctamente pero al intentar realizar el envío de un emil sin aplicar filtros sale la pantalla de error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Me gstaría saber si el error lo puede estar dando mi código PHP o si bien es un problema del servidor. Os dejo a continuación el código de los tres archivos que nvían el e-mail.

**Archivo: config.inc.php**

```
<?php
//Base de datos
define('SERVER', 'localhost');
define('USER', 'app_basconia');
define('PASSWORD', '*******');
define('BD', 'app_basconia');

//URL Base
define('URL_BASE', 'http://appbasconiaberria.launet.net/');

//PHPMailler
define('DEBUGOUTPUT', 'html');
define('HOST', 'smtp.serviciodecorreo.es');
define('SMTP_PORT', 587);
define('SMTP_SECURE', 'tls');
define('SMTP_AUTH', TRUE);
define('USERNAME', 'emailejemplo@emailejemplo.com');
define('MAIL_PASS', '********');
define('FROM_NAME', 'Nombre de la empresa');
define('FROM_EMAIL', 'emailejemplo@emailejemplo.com');
```

**Archivo: SendEmail.inc.php**

```
<?php

class SendEmail {

    private $mail;
    private $debugoutput;
    private $host;
    private $port;
    private $smtpSecure;
    private $smtpAuth;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $fromEmail;
    private $fromName;
    private $addressEmail;
    private $addressName;
    private $subject;
    private $msg;

    public function __construct($addressEmail, $addressName, $subject, $msg) {
        include_once 'app/configuration/config.inc.php';
        include_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        $this->mail = new PHPMailer();

        $this->debugoutput = DEBUGOUTPUT;
        $this->host = HOST;
        $this->port = SMTP_PORT;
        $this->smtpSecure = SMTP_SECURE;
        $this->smtpAuth = SMTP_AUTH;
        $this->username = USERNAME;
        $this->password = MAIL_PASS;
        $this->fromEmail = FROM_EMAIL;
        $this->fromName = utf8_decode(FROM_NAME);
        $this->addressEmail = $addressEmail;
        $this->addressName = utf8_decode($addressName);
        $this->subject = utf8_decode($subject);
        $this->msg = $msg;
    }

    private function prepararEmail() {
        $this->mail->isSMTP();
        $this->mail->Debugoutput = $this->debugoutput;
        $this->mail->Host = $this->host;
        $this->mail->Port = $this->port;
        $this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $this->mail->SMTPAutoTLS = FALSE;
        $this->mail->SMTPAuth = $this->smtpAuth;
        $this->mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        );
        $this->mail->SMTPDebug = true;
        $this->mail->Username = $this->username;
        $this->mail->Password = $this->password;
        $this->mail->setFrom($this->addressEmail, $this->fromName);
        $this->mail->addReplyTo('sentokujidai@gmail.com');
        $this->mail->addAddress($this->addressEmail, $this->addressName);
        $this->mail->Subject = $this->subject;
        $this->mail->msgHTML($this->msg);
    }

    public function enviar() {
        $this->prepararEmail();

        if ($this->mail->send()) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            var_dump('Error: ' . $this->mail->ErrorInfo);
            //return FALSE;
        }
    }

}
```

**Archivo sendEmail.php (Este se encarga de enviar el e-mail)**

```
<?php
include_once 'app/libraries/SendEmail.inc.php';

$titulo = 'Envío de e-mails';

include_once 'app/views/documentoInicio.php';

$msg = '';
$errorEmail = '';

if (isset($_POST['accion'])) {
    $archivo = $_FILES['archivo'];
    
    Conexion::abrirConexion();
    $arrayContactos = Contacto_model::getAllNoLimit(Conexion::getConexion(), $_POST['nombre'], $_POST['cp'], $_POST['localidad'], $_POST['provincia']);
    $totalContactos = Contacto_model::countAllNoLimit(Conexion::getConexion(), $_POST['nombre'], $_POST['cp'], $_POST['localidad'], $_POST['provincia']);
    $firma = Firma_model::getFirma(Conexion::getConexion());
    $arrayEmails = Firma_model::getEmails(Conexion::getConexion());
    $arrayLinks = Firma_model::getLinks(Conexion::getConexion());
    Conexion::cerrarConexion();
    if (count($arrayContactos)) {
        $emailsEnviados = 0;
        foreach ($arrayContactos as $contacto) {
            $cabeceraTexto = 'Estimado cliente de la empresa '. utf8_decode($contacto['cliente']->getNombre()).':';
            
            if (!is_null($contacto['contacto']->getNombreContacto())) {
                $cabeceraTexto = 'Estimado '.$contacto['contacto']->getNombreContacto();
                if (!is_null($contacto['contacto']->getDepartamento())) {
                    $cabeceraTexto .= ' del departamento de '. utf8_decode($contacto['contacto']->getDepartamento());
                }
                $cabeceraTexto .= ' de la empresa '.utf8_decode($contacto['cliente']->getNombre()).':';
            }
            
            $msgHTML = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3-org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><title>Diseño email</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><style>body {font-family: "Arial";font-size: 12px;}p.header {color: #507656;font-size: 10px;font-weight: bold;padding-top: 5px;}td.footer {padding: 10px;font-size: 12px;}.tabulacion {margin-left: 38px;}.tabulacion2 {margin-left: 32px;}</style></head><body style=""><table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td><table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;"><tr style="background-color: #ffffff;"><td style="padding: 20px 50px;"><p>';
            $msgHTML .= utf8_decode($cabeceraTexto).'</p>';
            $msgHTML .= utf8_decode($_POST['texto']);
            $msgHTML .= '</td></tr><tr><td class="footer" style="border-top: 1px solid #cd1719;"><p><img src="'.RUTA_IMG.'logo_berria1.png" alt="logotipo de Basconia Berria" /></p>';
            $msgHTML .= '<p style="color: #507656;"><strong>'.$firma->getTextoCabecera().'</strong></p><p>DEPARTAMENTO DE VENTAS<br /><strong style="color: #cd1719;">CONTACTOS</strong><br /><strong>Telefono:</strong> '.$firma->getTelefonos().'<br />';
            $emailPos = 1;
            if (count($arrayEmails)) {
                foreach ($arrayEmails as $emailFirma) {
                    $departamentoTxt = '';
                    if (!is_null($emailFirma->getDepartamento())) {
                        $departamentoTxt = 'DPTO. '.$emailFirma->getDepartamento().' ';
                    }
                    if ($emailPos == 1) {
                        $msgHTML .= '<strong>Email:</strong> '.$departamentoTxt.'<a href="mailto:'.$emailFirma->getEmail().'">'.$emailFirma->getEmail().'</a><br />';
                    } else {
                        $msgHTML .= $departamentoTxt.'<a href="mailto:'.$emailFirma->getEmail().'" class="tabulacion">'.$emailFirma->getEmail().'</a><br />';
                    }
                    $emailPos++;
                }
            }
            $linkPos = 1;
            if (count($arrayLinks)) {
                foreach ($arrayLinks as $linkFirma) {
                    if ($linkPos == 1) {
                        $msgHTML .= '<strong>Web:</strong>  <a href="'.$linkFirma->getUrl().'" target="_blank">'.$linkFirma->getTitulo().'</a><br />';
                    } else {
                        $msgHTML .= '<a href="'.$linkFirma->getUrl().'" target="_blank" class="tabulacion2">'.$linkFirma->getTitulo().'</a><br />';
                    }
                    $linkPos++;
                }
            }
            $msgHTML .= '</p></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></body></html>';
            
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Debugoutput = DEBUGOUTPUT;
            $mail->Host = HOST;
            $mail->Port = SMTP_PORT;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = SMTP_SECURE;
            $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = FALSE;
            $mail->SMTPAuth = SMTP_AUTH;
            $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
            );
            //$mail->SMTPDebug = TRUE;
            $mail->Username = USERNAME;
            $mail->Password = MAIL_PASS;
            $mail->setFrom('pedidos@basconiaberria.com', utf8_decode('Basconia Berria'));
            $mail->addReplyTo('pedidos@basconiaberria.com');
            $mail->addAddress($contacto['contacto']->getEmail());
            $mail->Subject = utf8_decode($_POST['asunto']);
            $mail->msgHTML($msgHTML);
            $mail->addAttachment($archivo['tmp_name'], $archivo['name']);
            
            //var_dump($mail->send());
            if ($mail->send()) {
                $emailsEnviados++;
                //echo 'enviado<br>';
            } else {
                //echo 'No enviado<br>';
               $errorEmail .= '<p>Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo.'</p>';
            }
        }
        
        if ($emailsEnviados == $totalContactos) {
            $msg = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">E-mails enviados correctamente. <a href="' . URL_BASE . '">Volver al inicio</a>.</div>';
        } else {
            $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p>No se han enviado todos los e-mails, ocurriendo los siguientes errores:</p>'.$errorEmail.'<p>Contacta con el desarrollador para informar de estos errores.</p></div>';
        }
    } else {
        $msg = '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">No hay ningún cliente registrado, por lo que no hay a quién mandar el e-mail. <a href="' . URL_BASE . 'clientes/nuevo">Introduce algún cliente</a>.</div>';
    }
}

$datos = array(
    'msg' => $msg,
    'ruta_img' => RUTA_IMG
);

echo $twig->render('registroCreado.html.twig', $datos);

$ajax = '';

include_once 'app/views/documentoCierre.php';
```

La versión de PHP Mailer que estoy utilizano es la 5.2.23

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que podáis darme.

Comment: Yo te sugiero que los correos los envíes a través de un cron-job dentro de tu servidor. Éste, va a tener la característica de ejecutarse, por ejemplo, cada 10 minutos. Los correos siempre los vas a traer de 10 en 10, por ejemplo, con un LIMIT desde tu consulta. Ésto evitará que exista una sobre carga en phpmailer y pueda enviar correos respetando las configuraciones de tu servidor. Recuerda que los servidores tanto compartidos como privados tienen configuraciones diferentes. Algunos permiten enviar hasta 100 correos por hora y otros servidores de correo enviar más de esos 100. Saludos.

Comment: El problema es que el cliente quiere escribir los correos como si de un Outlook se tratase, y añadir filtro para enviarlos por Código postal o localidad para que dichos correos le lleguen a un cliente de una zona, además de que el envío se haga en el instante en el que ellos pulsan enviar, por lo que la opción del cron qedró descartada antes de empezar la programación.

Comment: Lamento no poder modelarte una solución concreta para tu problema a través de este medio, sin embargo, toma en cuenta mis sugerencias, Outllook, Gmail y más clientes de correo funcionan de otra manera y bajo otras cuestiones técnicas que no tienen  nada que ver con phpmailer ni con el proceso que haces tú con php. Recuerda lo que te comenté de revisar y respetar las configuraciones que tu servidor de correo te permita.